# Not being able to configure Spinnaker bitbucket pipeline

Tags: pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines, spinnaker

So, notification seems to be working on push event from bit bucket as it returning 200 status. Now on spinnaker (1.9.5) deck side I am configuring trigger and expected artifact in this way:

```
hal config artifact bitbucket account add spinnaker-bitbucket-cloud
hal config artifact bitbucket account delete spinnaker-bitbucket-cloud
hal config artifact bitbucket account add spinnaker-bitbucket-cloud --username mybitbucketuser --password
```

**Expected Artifact**
[image]

**Automated Triger**

[image]

**Deploy Manifest**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure Bitbucket artifacts.
You can follow this guide (written for github, but is mainly the same), to setup the artifact type
https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/artifacts/github/